# Hyperledger Composer - can't find transaction error

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-composer

I am making a blockchain application using hyperledger composer and have written my cto, with on transaction, and the script file with no visible errors. However, when i try submit a transaction it returns this error: Error: Could not find any transactions to execute for org.evidence.net.evidenceDeposit.

Here is my CTO file:

```
namespace org.evidence.net

enum type {
  o storage
  o device
  o physical
  
}

enum status {
 o collected
 o stored
 o withdrawn
}

asset EvidenceItem identified by evidenceItemId {
  o String evidenceItemId
  o String caseNo
  o type Type
  o status Status
  o String optionalHash optional
  --> person Holder
}

abstract participant person identified by id {
  o String id
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}

participant Investigator extends person {
  
}

participant EvidenceManager extends person {
  
}

participant FRT extends person {
  
}

transaction evidenceDeposit {
  --> EvidenceItem EvidenceItem
  --> EvidenceManager EvidenceManager
}

event FirstDeposit {
  o String evidenceItemId
  o String  id
}
```

And here is my script file:

```
/*
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


/**
* Transfer evidence from FRT to Evidence Manager
* @param (org.evidence.net.evidenceDeposit} tx - the evidenceDeposit transaction
* @transaction
*/

const NS = 'org.evidence.net';


async function evidenceDeposit(tx) {
    // get asset registry for evidenceItem
  const evidenceItemRegistry = await getAssetRegistry(NS + '.evidenceItem');
  
  //Get participant registry for Evidence Manager
  const EvidenceManagerRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.EvidenceManager');
  
  const evidenceItem = await evidenceItemRegistry.get(tx.evidenceItem.getIdentifier());
    //Make sure that the evidenceItem exists
  
  if (!evidenceItem) {
    throw new Error(' Evidence with id ${tx.evidenceItem.getIdentifier()} does not exist');
    exit();
  }
  
  if (evidenceItem.status !== 'collected') {
    throw new Error('Evidence with id ${tx.evidenceItem.getIdentifier()} is not in collected status');
  }
  
  // Get Evidence Manager ID
  const EvidenceManagerID = tx.EvidenceManager.getIdentifier();
  
 //Make sure Evidence Manager exists
  const EvidenceManager = await EvidenceManagerRegistry.get(EvidenceManagerID);
  if(!EvidenceManager) {
    throw new Error('Evidence Manager with id ${EvidenceManagerID} does not exist');
  }
  
  //Update evidenceItem with new owner
  tx.evidenceItem.holder = tx.EvidenceManager;
  tx.evidenceItem.status = 'stored';
  
  //Update the asset in the asset registry
  await evidenceItemRegistry.update(tx.evidenceItem);
  
  //Create deposit event
  let FirstDepositEvent = getFactory().newEvent(NS, 'FirstDeposit');
  FirstDepositEvent.evidenceItemId = tx.evidenceItem.evidenceItemId;
  FirstDepositEvent.id = tx.EvidenceManager.id;
  
  // Emit the Event
  emit(FirstDepositEvent);
}
```

I have looked around and can't seem to find the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As per the answer below, you don't want to be using composer anymore as it is end of life and the community has moved on. You should be using the various sdks provided by hyperledger fabric instead

Answer (score 4):

Please see the readme below as Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated for over a year.
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md